# Accessing login-shell variables (from counsel-find-file)

Tags: counsel, system-environment

With `#'counsel-find-file`, I can type `$` to access environment
variables, but it appears these belong to a special emacs environment
and are not login-shell-wide.  Can I access the latter kind of variable
as well?